# Two hearted riddle

Tags: riddle, cipher, rhyme

Here is a riddle which has two parts,
here is a riddle about two hearts.

PART ONE.
I can help you find places, but where would you find me?
I can help you enter places that you shouldn't be.
What is it that you do when you touch me all day?
You can listen for me, but what's my underage name?

If you know what I am, then I'll ask you this, three endings you should see.
Use my heart twice, and you'll only just see the other half of me.

PART TWO.
I am help, but only when needed,
And I could touch your heart, but there's no time for romance.
I am a way, but only if you remove my two hearts.
Can you work out what I am?

Keep in mind the beginnings of this part, and also remember PART ONE.
If you know what I am, when I am, then you can: name me, and you'll be done.

EDIT: There are many steps to this puzzle. Feel free to post partials!

HINT:

> This riddle as a whole just seems overwhelming to solve. Thankfully, it's split into two parts. Why not just focus on the first? In fact, that first part is split into two as well...

Comment: That [cipher] tag is interesting ...

Comment: I suppose it is :)

Comment: In PART ONE, should there be a line break before "You can listen for me"?

Comment: Yup, sorry! Formatting on phone, argh. Made the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Riddle 1:**

> As explained by **[@Mithrandir](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47477/30633)**, the answer to this riddle is **KEY**

**Riddle 2:**

> The answer is **DOCTOR**

I am help, but only when needed,

> the Doctor shows up when needed, but doesn't hang around

And I could touch your heart, but there's no time for romance.

> the Doctor touches all our hearts, but doesn't have a romantic partner

I am a way, but only if you remove my two hearts.

> remove the two hearts, leaving DO<s>CT</s>OR → DOOR, a way

Can you work out what I am?

> ... two hearts.  of course, a Gallifreyan.

### Last part

Keep in mind the beginnings of this riddle, and also remember PART ONE.
If you know what I am, when I am, then you can: name me, and you'll be done.

> Beginnings of this riddle are the first letter of each line, IAICKI.
>  Remember PART ONE, which gave "KEY" and "PEER", as explained by **[@TechIdiot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47482/30633)**.
>  Use "PEER" as a Vigenere key on IAICKI, gives "TWELVE".

**Putting it all together ...**

> **You are the Twelfth Doctor.**

Comment: Nice. :) Also good to note is that the standard definition of Doctor works here!

Answer (score 4):

## Partial

First paragraph:

> key

I can help you find places, but where would you find me?

> A **key** on a map.

I can help you enter places that you shouldn't be.

> Things that are locked,

What is it that you do when you touch me all day?

> Type, on a keyboard

You can listen for me, but what's my underage name?

> Something to do with music. Possibly a minor chord/scale?

Answer (score 2):

The second part of the first half gives -

> **PEER**

Explanations

> There are three questions, which leads to answers MAP/TYPE/MINOR
>  Taking endings we get PER. Double the heart we get - > P E E R -> **PEER**

[Added by OP]:

> 'Only just see' is a definition for peer.

Comment: Could I edit to add the final confirmation of this answer in the puzzle?

Comment: Sure. Go ahead :)